# Not able to edit a entity object asp.net

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a function that takes in a viewModel like this.

```
 public ActionResult(ViewModel viewModel)
 {
       var entityObject = _context.User.Find(viewModel.User.Id);
       entityObject = viewModel.User;
       _context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

I can see that the entityObject is changed (when debugging) but the information isn't stored to the database. Do I have to add all attributes manually in the following way:

```
 entityObject.Name = viewModel.User.Name;
 entityObject.Age = viewModel.User.Age;
```

I have tried setting the state of entityObject to modified but then it just throws already attached.

All suggestions are appreciated.

The database context is injected into the controller's constructor (if that matters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You have to map the values over; you cannot simply just stuff a different instance in the same variable. The instance on your view model isn't tracked, so EF has no idea it should do anything with it. The only thing it's tracking is the `User` instance originally stored in `entityObject`, which you are effectively destroying by replacing the variable value with the instance from your view model.

As far as doing this manually goes, you can opt to use something like AutoMapper to handle the bulk of this for you, but there's nuances to using a mapping library like that. At the very least, you have to register your type mappings, but you may also need to create custom resolvers or define manual mapping procedures for the mapped types. It just depends on what you're doing and how complex the mapping logic becomes.

Regardless of *how* you do the mapping, you definitely must do it, though. There's no free lunch here.

Answer (score 0):

You can update values without enumerating all properties like this :

```
var entity = _collection.Find(item.Id);
if (entity == null)
{
    return;
}

_context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
```

The Update method of Entity Framework works the same.

Also, other options like AutoMapper or Mapster exists.

Comment: This is *very* dangerous, as you're now allowing overpost exploits - defeats the entire point of using a view model.